# Showing that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 f(g(x)^n)dx$ exists and lies in the interval $[f(0), f(1)]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $g : [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ is a Lebesgue measurable function. Let $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous with $f(0) \le f(1)$. Show that the $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 f(g(x)^n)dx$ exists and lies in the interval $[f(0), f(1)]$ .

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

Is this attempt correct? (I'm not sure how more rigorously I can write that)

Since $f$ is continuous over a compact set $[0,1]$ it attains its extremes. Let $f_n = f(g(x)^n)$ then since $f$ is continuous $f_n$ is measurable and by the fact $f$ attains its maximum $f_n \le M$ for some $M>0$.

moreover, by continuity of $f$ we'd have that

$(\ast) \lim_{n\to\infty} f(g(x)^n) = f(\lim_{n\to\infty} g(x)^n) =\left\{\begin{matrix}
f(1) & \text{if} \ g(x)=1\\ 
f(0) & \ \text{if} \ 0\le g(x) <1
\end{matrix}\right. $

So, using dominated convergence theorem we'd have ;

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 f(g(x)^n)dx 
& =  \int_0^1\lim_{n\to\infty} f(g(x)^n)dx\\ 
&= \int_0^1f(\lim_{n\to\infty} g(x)^n)dx = \left\{\begin{matrix}
f(1) & \text{if} \ g(x)=1\\ f(0) & \ \text{if} \ 0\le g(x) <1
\end{matrix}\right . \\
\end{align}

Comment: Almost. the very last equation is not correct. It should be $Af(1)+(1-A)f(0)$, where $A$ is the measure of the set where $g(x)=1$ and $1-A$ the measure of the complement.